# Promediar (AVG) campos tipo TIME en MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos, date, mysql-workbench

Hola estoy creando una aplicación para el control de uso en un estacionamiento, utilizo MySQL Workbench 8.0, en la BD tengo la tabla que almacena los registros, una columna es quien guarda el tiempo de uso de cada vehículo como un tipo de dato **TIME**, de forma **HH:MM:SS**:

[image]

Quisiera saber como obtener el promedio de estos valores, utilicé la función **AVG()** de la siguiente manera:

```sql
SELECT AVG(tiempo_uso) FROM registrolugarestacionamiento;
```

Pero me devuelve un resultado sin formato de tiempo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Hay alguna forma de obtener el promedio con el formato de hora **HH:MM:SS**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como el dato no es un numero primero debes convertirlo mediante TIMESTAMP, luego de eso ya podrás usar las funciones numéricas.

```
SELECT
    FROM_UNIXTIME(AVG(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(tiempo_uso)), '%h:%i:%s')
FROM
    registrolugarestacionamiento;
```

Comment: funciona bien, pero cuando los registros son únicamente en minutos, véase 00:28:00,00:28:00,00:28:00, el promedio debería ser 00:28:00 ¿verdad? sin embargo me devuelve 12:28:00 ¿estoy omitiendo algo?